# How do I separate html code and php code and get the same effect when i run the code?

Tags: php, css, html

I'm making a calculator to a webbsite. I have my php and html code on the same file but need to put them in separate files (a requirement for my course). I have tried using `<form action = "cal.php">`, and even though it works it puts the result on a different page and not on the exact spot on the screen i want it to show up.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>Something</title>
</head>

<body>

  <form>
    <input type="text" name="num1" placeholder="Tal 1">

    <input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="Tal 2">

        <select name="operator"><!-- used to choose which operator to calculate with from the php code -->

            <option>Operation One</option> <!-- add -->

            <option>Operation Two</option> <!-- sub -->

        </select>

    <br>

    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Calculate </button>

  </form>

  <p>Result: </p>
  <!-- php code -->

</body>


</html>
```

If i have the code on the same file i get the answer on the same page and exactly after "Result:", but when i separate them the answer prints out on a new blank page and in the corner. How do I get the same effect as if they were on the same file?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "how"? Have you tried looking up templating engines? That's the best use case for them

Comment: Did you mean running it as an AJAX function so it will calculate and then input into the current page without reloading?

Comment: I'm new to all of this, but I can only use php, css and html. I have to put the php code on a separate file, but when i do that I get the result on a new blank page. After it had calculated, say 3+3, i want the result 6, on the same page as the boxes and on exactly the place i want it to be. I hope I'm clear?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is mix PHP with HTML. Not the best way, because you should sepearte logic from Template/Output. To do this there are some PHP Templating Enginges that will help you.

If your are starting with PHP, the following will do the trick. Maybe it is necessary to change the file ending from .html to .php but it depends on your webserver configuration.

```html
<?php 

//include your file calc.php to access the functions, see https://php.net/require
require 'calc.php';

// do your fancy stuff an set your calculation result
$result = ...
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>Something</title>
</head>

<body>

  <form action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="num1" placeholder="Tal 1">

    <input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="Tal 2">

        <select name="operator"><!-- used to choose which operator to calculate with from the php code -->

            <option>Operation One</option> <!-- add -->

            <option>Operation Two</option> <!-- sub -->

        </select>

    <br>

    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Calculate </button>

  </form>

  <p>Result: </p>
  <!-- php code -->

  <?php echo $result; ?>

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try updating the result of the button as a link with `target` pointing to `_self` ?

Example :

```
<a href="#" target="_self">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Calculate </button>
<a/>
```

Maybe an event a `_top` attribute, like :

```
<a href="#" target="_top">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Calculate </button>
<a/>
```

Or even add JavaScript on the `<button>` or `<a>` :

1st way :

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('your_html', '_self')"> <!-- or change to _top -->
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">Calculate</button>
</a>
```

2nd way :

```
<a href="#">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="window.open('your_html', '_self')">Calculate</button> <!-- or change to _top -->
</a>
```